# Are all my Ankhs of Reincarnations consumed when you die?

Tags: werewolv.es

If you die with multiple Ankhs of Reincarnations, will one of them or all of them be consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will all trigger and all be consumed.

Comment: That's disappointing! ;D No near-immortality achieved by ankh stacking then